# Creating A Custom Button

Tags: custom-button, urlhacking

Right now, when I go to an account such as "Netflex" and click on "New Opportunity" on the related list.  I then can create a new opportunity with the account name automatically populated for you.  How can I do this on a custom button?

Thanks

Comment: One way is via a url hack - google "Salesforce url hack" will bring up a ton of examples. Are you only interested in prepopulating the Account field or are there other fields you would like to prepopulate, and with what value? Adding this detail will help us provide a much more helpful answer.

Comment: Thanks Girbot, right now it is just the account id field.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to populate the standard Account field only, then the HTML ID that should interest you is **accid** :

Create button as like the screenshot below :

[image]

and enter button or link URL as -
**/006/e?retURL=%2F{!Account.Id}&accid={!Account.Id}&ent=Opportunity**

Answer (score 0):

You can populate the Account field through URL hacking:

put in the URL the account name as a value of page input id:
/006/e?opp4={!Account.Name}

opp4 = input element id in HTML in object layout (click on inspect in browser to see the input element id)

[image]

the following link has detailed instructions on how to do this:
https://focusonforce.com/configuration/salesforce-url-hacking/